# Failed - Instruction bfunc is not supported

Tags: qiskit

Here I want to run my code on a quantum computer using [IBM Quantum Platform](https://quantum-computing.ibm.com/). But I am receiving this error **Failed - Instruction bfunc is not supported**.

```
    provider = IBMQ.get_provider(hub='ibm-q', group='open', project='main')
    backend = provider.get_backend('ibm_perth')

    qr = QuantumRegister(4)
    cr = ClassicalRegister(2)
    circuit = QuantumCircuit(qr,cr)
    circuit.x(qr[0])
    circuit.x(qr[1])
    circuit.ccx(qr[0], qr[1], qr[2])
    circuit.x(qr[1])
    circuit.ccx(qr[0], qr[1], qr[3])
    circuit.x(qr[0])
    circuit.measure(qr [0],cr[0])
    circuit.measure(qr [1],cr[1])
    mapped_circuit = transpile(qc, backend=backend)
    qobj = assemble(mapped_circuit, backend=backend, shots=1)
```

[image]
The error I received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perth is on the list of upcoming deprecated devices: https://qiskit.slack.com/archives/CJG2E9LQP/p1690488935013449

It seems ***ibm_perth*** does support dynamic circuits.
We can check out this link for info on how to run dynamic circuits (which is what you need to run ***c_if***).
https://docs.quantum-computing.ibm.com/build/getting-started-with-dynamic-circuits